# Can we write independent of machine(i.e. independent of OS) code in asp.net?

Tags: c#

As i have read MSIL manages the code to make it independent of machine;but i have also read that DOT NET just provide windows independence not Plateform.
Please Explain if

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically and technically .NET provides platform independence. Practically there are no implementations from Microsoft of .NET outside Windows for obvious reasons. There is Mono for other platforms that is mostly compatible but you need to check if the part of the framework you are using is supported on Mono. Most of ASP.NET is supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) on Linux and Macintosh

For Mono compatibility, look here: http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Answer is 50:50. IL code is equivalent to Java byte code. Byte code is understood by JVM whereas IL code is understood by CLR. At present there are JVM versions available for almost every OS, almost every processor architecture and what not. However this is not the case for CLR. Microsoft version of CLR is exclusively available for Windows only. Hence you are "virtually" tied up to platform.

Flip side of story is that [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is another version of CLR which is being backed by Novell and it is capable of running Windows Forms application as well as ASP.Net application. But their version is usually 1 version behind MS version. HTH

Comment: "At present there are JVM versions available for every OS" Really? Can you provide a link for the iOS version of the JVM?

Comment: Accepted. It is not there for iOS. Would I be wrong claiming if that is the only OS not to have it?

Comment: Of course you will be wrong. "Every OS" is very bold claim. How about Windows Phone 7 :) I believe you can even find modern server OS that is specialized for specific needs and lacks a JVM. You can say something like "every major server and desktop OS" but "every OS" is just too much.

Comment: You got me there and yes many OSs built for some specialized purpose will not have it. Edited my stance on it. :)